# Choosing the appropriate version of Python runtime to use along with TensorFlow

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

How can I choose the appropriate version of Python runtime to use along with TensorFlow 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would invite you to check the TensorFlow [installation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) which gives all the detail for your specific system. At the moment, TensorFlow supports Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, although it seems 3.6 does not yet have GPU support. If you're starting out with Python, you should probably get 3.5 (if you need GPU) or 3.6 (if you'll only use CPU). Python 2.7 was released a long time ago.

If you don't already have Python, you can get it from the [Python website](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download). However, I recommend you get Python through [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) so that you get all necessary packages to run things like TensorFlow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any idea about differences in performance between Tensor-flow using Python 2.7 and +3.5 runtime ?

Comment: Heavy computation in TensorFlow does not depend on a specific Python version, since computation is done with things like BLAS (low level routines for linear algebra in C), and cuDNN (library for neural net operations on NVIDIA GPUs). Generally speaking, it seems that Python 3x has been faster for awhile now, see [here](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/python-3-dot-3-trust-me-its-better-than-python-2-dot-7-by-dr-brett-cannon) for example. The only reason to use 2.7 is if you have no other option because of a dependency. In my experience this never came up for TensorFlow.